# django long running process database connection

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

i have a django project with a long running (~3hour) management command
in my production environment ( apache mod_wsgi ) this process fails with a broken pipe(32) at the end, when trying to update the database.

thank you

Comment: You shouldn't run such long running commands within context of the web processes as for certain Apache configurations processes could be killed off and restarted at any time. You should run such commands from separately invoked process that run in the background and disassociated from the web processes. If done on a regular schedule for example, then trigger it from cron.

Comment: yes, it is done with cron, it interacts through the django system via manage.py <custom_command>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broken pipe mostly mean that one socket in the canal of transmission has been closed without notifying the other one , in your case i think it mean that the database connection that you have establish was closed from the database part, so when you code try to use it, it raise the exception.

Usually the database connection has a time out which "usually" you can configure by making it more bigger to solve this kind of problem , check your database documentation to see how.

N.B: you don't give us much detail so i'm just trying to make assumption here.

Well hope this can help.